# Sorting objects by a value within them

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects, these objects all have multiple values stored within them. I have them within an object array.

```
class PlayerScores {

String playerName;
   int pos=0;
   int played=0;
   int win=0;
   int draw=0;
   int lose=0;
   int goalsFor=0;
   int goalsAgainst=0;
   int goalDifference=0;
   int points=0;

   public PlayerScores() {
   }
}
```

These are stored within the array:

```
Player Scores[] playersObjects = new PlayerScores[int];

            playersObjects[i] = new PlayerScores();
```

I want to search through 'playersObject[]' and order then in a new object array with the Player with the highest points first in the array and the rest in descending order. I am not sure how to run a sort on a single value within an object.

Any help would be massively appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Comment: @PeterO. this is *slightly* different since it's with an array instead of an `ArrayList` (i.e. use `Arrays.sort` instead of `Collections.sort`), though admittedly it's markedly similar and doubtless there's another question out there that covers the same material *somewhere* on SO...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays.Sort`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5b%5d,%20int,%20int,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E%29) and provide a custom [`Comparator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html). Something like this should work:

```
public class PlayerScoresComparator implements Comparator<PlayerScores> {
    @Override
    public int compare(PlayerScores lhs, PlayerScores rhs) {
        return lhs.points - rhs.points;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, (sorry for my being a noob) but I am still unsure how to do this. How do I make a custom Comparator, I have read through the API and an struggling to see how I would select only the int .points from my object and compare those with all the other ones.

Comment: I cannot find in the Comparator how to get a certain variable from the class anywhere.

Comment: @OliBlack Added an implementation of a `Comparator` based on your class.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to what kabuko suggested, you could use an [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) of PlayerScore objects, while implementing [Comparable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and adding a compareTo(PlayerScore another) method to PlayerScore class, like this:

```
public class PlayerScores implements Comparable<PlayerScores> {
  [...]

public int compareTo(PlayerScore another) {
  //example of a method to calculate which ogject is "greater".
  //See Comparable documentation for details. You will need to implement proper logic
  return getHighScore() - another.getHighScore(); 
}
```

Then you will be able to sort the ArrayList by Collections.sort():

```
ArrayList<PlayerScores> scores = new ArrayList<PlayerScores>();
[...] //Populate scores list
Collections.sort(scores)
```

This will be useful if you're have to use an ArrayList anyways, i.e. if you're going to attach it to a ListView.